# Svg getComputedTextLength function always returning zero

Tags: svg, d3.js

Hello I tried to integrate this d3 zoomable treemap from

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html

but the `getComputedTextLength()` always returns 0. I also tried `getBBox()`, but it returns an object with all properties with zero.

```
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
         d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); 
         return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0;
    });
```

Do I need to put my text wrapped in a `tspan`?
What other reasons could generate this?

Comment: So what you're saying is that you're using the exact same code and it doesn't work for you?

Comment: yes everything works fine, except i always get 0 for getComputedTextLength, so my text opacity always set to 1

Comment: If you're using the exact same code as the one you've linked to it must be a browser bug.

Comment: using google chrome if i set a breakpoint:                                    > this
<text x=​"17.110570629550967" y=​"16.420567484327563" dy=​".35em" text-anchor=​"middle">​EC 6191A​</text>​                                                          
 > this.getComputedTextLength()
0

Comment: yes but with the same browser, i can see the example

Comment: So you have changed it? What changes did you make?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I realize that this is over a year late, but I ran into the same issue recently and this may help someone. `this.getComputedTextLength()` returns 0 if the `text` element hasn't been rendered yet or if the container or any of its parent containers have `display` set to `none` at the time the `text` element is being rendered.

Comment: I should have googled this first, it would've saved me a lot of time! By adding a small `setTimeout` to the rendering of the text after the svg became visible solved my issue

Comment: @mar asks: Can you please add how to target the text element after it has been rendered?

Comment: is there a possiblity to execute code when the element is rendered?? Because `setTimeout` seems not to be a very nice solution to me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. My top level `svg` parent node had not yet been appended to the DOM so `getComputedTextLength` always returned `0`. This helped me figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem now in 2021, but i was able to figure it out by using `d3.select(this).node().getComputedTextLength();`, take a look at the following code lines:

```
.text(function (d) {
    return this.getValueText(d);
})
.attr('font-size', function (d) {
    d.computedTextLength = d3.select(this).node().getComputedTextLength();
    return self.getFontSizeForItem(d);
});
```