# D3 call to getComputedTextLength() returns zero

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using several D3 charts that are in a slider window to "slide" in and out of sight. According to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26249232/4483783) to a similar problem the answer stated that "this.getComputedTextLength() returns 0 if the text element hasn't been rendered yet or if the container or any of its parent containers have display set to none at the time the text element is being rendered".

This seems to not be an issue with Chrome but only with IE and Firefox.

This is the cause of the issue but is there a solution that will cause getComputedTextLength() to always return a non-zero value?

Comment: Yes, render the text element.

Comment: You could render the text element somewhere off screen.